# Fixed positioned div inside of relative positioned div causes strange overscroll behavior in mobile Safari

Tags: css, mobile-safari

When I position a fixed div inside of a relative div, and align the fixed div to the bottom of the viewport, then attempt to scroll past the bottom in mobile Safari (iOS 13) I get a strange effect. It looks as though the div becomes obscured by a white rectangle. Is there any way to prevent this behavior without changing the `position` of the outer or inner divs?

[image]

```css
.outer {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 5px;
}

.inner {
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1030;
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
      test test test <br/> test test test
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Did you try setting `height` or `min-height` on `.inner` class?

Answer (score 1):

The `.inner` content goes outside the boundaries of the `.outer` wrapper. 
You'd need to set `overflow` to `visible` on the `.outer` parent to make its content visible outside of its relative parent.

See the result : https://codepen.io/romainpetit/pen/BaNLaZr

Tested.

```
.outer {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 5px;
}

.inner {
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1030;
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
}
```